# Appications of partial derivatives

Tags: partial-differential-equations

A small plane uses fuel at the rate of r = r(h, v) litres per hour when it is flying
at a height of h meters above the ground and its velocity is v km/h. At a moment
when the plane has an altitude of 8000m and a speed of 120km/h, its height
is increasing at 500m per minute and it is accelerating at 3km per minute. At
what rate is its fuel consumption rate increasing or decreasing at that moment if
h = 8000 and v = 120, the function r and its derivatives have the values r = 7.2
liters per hour, ∂r
∂h = −2X10−4 per hour per meter and ∂r
∂v = 0.13 liters per hour
per kilometer.

Comment: i was trying to find the formular which relates r ,h and v but thats becoming so tough to an extent i cant go further and use the correct techniques of applications of partial derivatives

Comment: im now stuck and really need help...Thank you

Comment: managed to ffind the solution will try to post it soon